# In eclipse for selenium program , Error- main method not found in class driver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am learning selenium in eclipse but following error comes out-

Error: Main method not found in class driver, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

i already added selenium jar and selenium standalone jar files in buildpath but
error still exists, here's the code

```
 import org.apache.xpath.operations.String;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


   public class driver{

   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new FirefoxDriver();

    }
    }
```

i thoroughly  searched, but not able to find the solution , please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your imports, you should not be using:

```
import org.apache.xpath.operations.String;
```

By doing this you're making the compiler use the "org.apache.xpath.operations.String" instead of the normal "java.lang.String"
If you remove this import it will work just fine.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks thebobblob
also how can i debug these kind of problems