# I am trying to automate webservices by using java. I tried in two ways by using java method and using testNg annotations

Tags: java, web-services, automation, soapui

```
@Test
public void m1(){

    System.out.println("Hi");
    System.out.println("I am writing script for Cucucmber");
    RestAssured.baseURI="http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city";
    RequestSpecification httpRequest=RestAssured.given();
    Response response=httpRequest.request(Method.GET,"/Hyderabad");
    String reponcexml=response.getBody().asString();
    System.out.println("Response body :"+reponcexml);
}
```

while i am trying with above code i am facing below issue.

Error: Main method not found in class cucumber_Startup.Cucumber_First, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? It is not really clear if you want to write a test that calls a webservice OR want to write an application that calls the webservice.

Comment: i am trying to automate restApi services only

Comment: Can you please provide the complete class. This could be an issue with imports like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049457/in-eclipse-for-selenium-program-error-main-method-not-found-in-class-driver

Comment: import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.Method;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;;

public class WeatherReport {

 
 public static void main(String[] args){
  RestAssured.baseURI="http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city";
  RequestSpecification httpRequest=RestAssured.given();
  Response response=httpRequest.request(Method.GET,"/Hyderabad");
  String reponcexml=response.getBody().asString();
  System.out.println("Response body :"+reponcexml);
 }
}

Comment: What is your requirement here ? I can see rest assured libs being imported but your error and your print statement says "cucumber". Do you want to use cucumber or rest assured or rest assured with cucumber ?

Comment: i.e my class name only ...i am using existed class name...

Comment: restAssured_automation_weatherReport
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.Method;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class WeatherReport {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  RestAssured.baseURI="http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city";
  RequestSpecification httpRequest=RestAssured.given();
  Response response=httpRequest.request(Method.GET,"/Hyderabad");
  String reponcexml=response.getBody().asString();
  System.out.println("Response body :"+reponcexml);
 }
}